# Red5 plugin in Eclipse, import cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, flash, red5

After installing the last versions of Red5, Eclipse and Infrared5 plugin, I create a new Dynamic Web Project with Red5 server runtime. The generated code is :

```
package org.red5.core;
import org.red5.logging.Red5LoggerFactory;
import org.red5.server.adapter.MultiThreadedApplicationAdapter;
import org.red5.server.api.IConnection;
import org.red5.server.api.scope.IScope;

public class Application extends MultiThreadedApplicationAdapter {
    //private static Logger log = Red5LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public boolean connect(IConnection conn, IScope scope, Object[] params) {
        //log.info("appConnect");
        return true;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void disconnect(IConnection conn, IScope scope) {
        //log.info("disconnect");
        super.disconnect(conn, scope);
    }
}
```

The imports fail, I get the error :

> Cannot find the class file for org.red5.server.api.IConnection.
>
> The type org.red5.server.api.IConnection cannot be resolved.
>
> It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Same for `org.red5.logging.Red5LoggerFactory` and `org.red5.server.api.scope.IScope`

I think maybe the plugin is out of date and it could be solved by changing the import locations... But I don't know the correct ones. Where can I get them for the last version of Red5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IConnection` has never been moved to my knowledge and the other imports are in their correct locations.

- [MultiThreadedApplicationAdapter](https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/blob/eda471d3a005adb2555ca2d59e18844825f813c4/src/main/java/org/red5/server/adapter/MultiThreadedApplicationAdapter.java)
- [IConnection](https://github.com/Red5/red5-server-common/blob/119f6e2f9dd35e0ca2eef125e59d867c51a9acf1/src/main/java/org/red5/server/api/IConnection.java)
- [IScope](https://github.com/Red5/red5-server-common/blob/119f6e2f9dd35e0ca2eef125e59d867c51a9acf1/src/main/java/org/red5/server/api/scope/IScope.java)

Not being a Red5 Eclipse plugin expert, I would expect that your plugin is not pointing at the correct location for the red5 jars. If you just want to use Eclipse for your Red5 development, you can use these guides [Eclipse Setup](https://www.red5pro.com/docs/server/eclipsesetup/) or [First Red5 App](https://www.red5pro.com/docs/server/red5prolive/) to get going (they do not require Pro)

Comment: Still not sure about the problem with the plugin, seems too outdated.. Thanks for the links to the imports, it means the sample codes I found online should work. I hadn't understood you could use the doc for Red5Pro in Red5 :)